# Editable DataGrid with Two way binding - Binding Only on Lost Focus

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

i have a editable datagrid in wpf. i have entered value of a column (ex.quantity) in a DataGridCell. the entered value binds only on the lost focus of the textbox. i need the latest value on the event of enter key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your column bindings

You need to set the `UpdateSpurceTrigger` property to `PropertyChanged`

```
"{Binding XXXX, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```